# .NET library to convert Microsoft Office docs to PDF

Tags: library, pdf, .net, document-converter, office

I am looking for a library (open source or paid) that can convert Microsoft Office documents (`.docx`, `.xlsx` etc.) and images to PDF. This library must be accessible from .NET.

I had a look at [ABCpdf](http://www.websupergoo.com/abcpdf-1.htm) but it requires a Microsoft Office installation on the server which I don't want. My documents are stored in a database so I want something that can work with byte arrays.

Can anybody recommend a library?

Comment: Do you require it to be a .NET library or would cmdline work?

Comment: Need a .net library. Using in a web-service.

Answer (score 3):

The [LEADTOOLS Documents SDK](https://www.leadtools.com/sdk/document) has the ability to convert all of the Microsoft Office formats and output as PDF in .NET.

Here is a list of all of the support formats that the SDK can convert from and to:

> - Adobe Acrobat PDF and PDF/A
>     Microsoft Office DOC/DOCX, XLS/XLSX, PPT/PPTX, PST, EML, MSG, and XPS formats
> - CAD formats such as DXF, DWG, and DWF
> - Plain Text, RTF, HTML, MOBI, ePUB
> - IBM AFP, MO:DCA, IOCA, and PTOCA

On top of all of these formats, you can also enable OCR and convert images to a document-based searchable PDF.

Disclaimer: I am an employee of this library

Comment: If I understood, these features - even OCR - are all available in both products : Document Imaging, Recognition, Document Imaging Suite, Medical Imaging, PACS Imaging, Medical Imaging Suite. Right ?

Comment: These features including OCR are included as part of Recognition Imaging and Document Imaging Suite and is available as an Addon for the other products you mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

[Aspose](http://www.aspose.com/) offers many different individual components:

1. Aspose.Cells:

   - Specializing in: XLS, XLSX, XLSM, SpreadsheetML, CSV, Tab Delimited, ODS, HTML, PDf documents

     - Load workbook
     - Advanced manipulation with SmartMarkers
     - Pivot table support
     - Convert workbooks from SharePoint document library
     - Save workbook
     - Export JasperReports to workbook
     - Workbook to PDF conversion
     - Manage worksheet
     - Worksheet to image conversion
     - Workbook security
     - Chart support
     - Export RDL reports to workbook
2. Aspose.Words

   - Specializing in: DOC, DOCX, RTF, FlatOpc, WordML, XML, ODT, TXT, HTML files.
   - Word processing documents to ODT, HTML, EPUB, TXT conversion

     - ODT, HTML, TXT to Microsoft Word and other word processing documents conversion
     - Word processing documents, HTML, MHTML, TXT and Open Document support
     - Assemble documents
     - Update fields
     - Insert content and formatting
     - Word processing documents to PDF, XPS, PS, SWF, XAML or SVG conversion
     - Print documents
     - Render pages to TIFF or other image formats such as PNG, BMP, EMF or JPEG
     - Mail merge/reporting
     - Populate from a database
     - Nested mail merge regions

They also have many more components for things such slideshows/PowerPoint, PDFs, barcodes, OneNote, imaging, OCR, diagrams/Visio, Tasks/Project, email and a few others.

Comment: Is Aspose.PDF able to convert Microsoft Office Documents to PDF without other Aspose components like Aspose.Word or Aspose.Excel ?

Answer (score 1):

[Essential PDF](http://asp.syncfusion.com/demos/web/pdf/doctopdf.aspx) can convert Word, PowerPoint and Excel documents to PDF and it doesn't require Microsoft Office. It is written in C# and available as a library for use from any .NET platform.

The [community license](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense) provides the whole suite of products for free.
-Davis (Syncfusion)

Comment: How can we purchase Essential PDF ? Is it included in some products or it is available as is ? [This page](https://www.syncfusion.com/products/file-formats/presentation) also seems to  say that Essential PDF can manage PowertPoint files. True ? If so, ppt AND pptx ?

Comment: @Amessihel: Essential PDF is included in several product bundles including the File Formats package https://www.syncfusion.com/sales/products/fileformats. The File Formats package also includes Essential Presentation that can manipulate PPTX files. The current list price for a developer license of Essential Studio File Formats Edition is USD$995. There is a 30 day trial also available from the product page itself.

Comment: thanks. Do you plan to add ppt format ?

Comment: @Amessihel I will check and confirm

Comment: Syncfusion provides a PowerPoint library as well https://www.syncfusion.com/powerpoint-framework/net

Answer (score 0):

I have used the components provided by [Sub Systems](http://www.subsystems.com/) to perform RTF to PDF conversion, but they also provide components for performing [DOCX to PDF](http://www.subsystems.com/dpw.htm) conversion. I haven't used them, but I like their RTF to PDF stuff.

They're paid for components, but the times I've had to use their support they've been pretty good compared to other third party components providers I've worked with in the past.

Answer (score 0):

You can check out our libraries:

- [GemBox.Document](http://www.gemboxsoftware.com/document/overview) (for converting DOCX to PDF and/or image format)
- [GemBox.Spreadsheet](http://www.gemboxsoftware.com/spreadsheet/overview) (for converting XLSX to PDF and/or image format)

They do not require Office installation and they can work with file's stream (or byte array) check [here](http://www.gemboxsoftware.com/support-center/kb/articles/30-working-with-document-file-stream) and [here](http://www.gemboxsoftware.com/support-center/kb/articles/31-working-with-spreadsheet-file-stream).

Comment: Just a warning : the net version of gembox does not print to pdf currently.

Comment: And will not in 2019 :
https://support.gemboxsoftware.com/feedback/view/add-pdf-support-in-net-standard

Comment: There are 2 DLL versions of both components; one is for .NET Framework which does support printing and saving to PDF, other is for .NET Standard which currently does not support this, but we plan to work on it.

Answer (score 0):

[Docmosis](http://www.docmosis.com) provides a web service API (REST) for document production based around word-processor style documents, using templates and merging data.  It can convert various formats including doc/docx/xls to pdf.  Please note I work for Docmosis.

Answer (score 0):

We use [Spire.Doc](http://www.e-iceblue.com) and this supports MailMerge and generating a PDF as a stream or File from the document.  We've used this in situations where we're pulling binary data from a database, manipulating/loading via streams and then streaming out the PDF.

I'd recommend checking out this library.

Answer (score 0):

**DISCLOSURE: I AM THE OWNER OF THIS PRODUCT.**

You can try our doc/docx to PDF Converter at http://converter-eval.plutext.com/

Its for Word documents only I'm afraid, not pptx, xlsx etc.

Its an on-premises server/service you can use in your application to programmatically convert or export Microsoft Word doc/docx files to PDF.

Highlights:

- aims to mimic Word's layout (high fidelity)
- produces PDF/A-2b compliant output
- is simple to install (especially compared to SharePoint, LibreOffice etc); should go without saying, but no need for Word to be installed.
- is fast (and multithreaded)
- is frugal with resources
- is secure (strict separation of conversion jobs)
- runs as an operating system service (on Windows or Linux).

.NET client code is at http://converter-eval.plutext.com/client_dotnet.html

Comment: What exactly is your affiliation with this product?  Please disclose.

Comment: As both the user name and the first line of the answer discloses, its my product :-)