# .NET library to convert DOCX to PDF

Tags: gratis, pdf, .net, microsoft-word

I have a need to convert Word documents (DOCX) to (PDF) programmatically from withing a .NET application without having Word installed.

In general, I'm very happy with [XCeed DocX](https://github.com/xceedsoftware/DocX), but the free version does not generate PDF. Thus, I do not need any other DOCX manipulation methods, just a conversion to PDF.

I have seen [this question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/10497/1935), but I need it gratis for non-commercial use (non-profit organization). Ideally it would be open source, so I can make modifications.

If possible, I'd like to avoid other huge programs (such as LibreOffice or Ghostscript) that require installation and might mess with customer's PC. I'd consider a 20 MB library still large, but acceptable.

Comment: I believe the only viable option for you is LibreOffice. Have you tried that? If so, what was the issue?

Comment: @Ryan: I have not tried LibreOffice. I'd prefer something more lightweight, like a DLL instead of installing a 100 MB product.